# Removing an entry from a list (class[function])

Tags: python, class

I'm using a class which has a function with the following code:

```
#delete the specified entry from the list if entry in list
def deleteEntry(self,entry):
    if entered in self.alist():
    remove.entered()
```

alist first asks the user for inputs.
How would you write a function that removes an entry from the list if it is in the list?
Thanks !
Using Python 3.3.1 BTW !

Answer (score 0):

```
def deleteEntry(self, entry):
    try:
        self.alist.remove(entry)
    except ValueError:
        pass # entry was not in the list
```

This is assuming that `self.alist` is the list you are hoping to remove items from.

Note that if `entry` may occur multiple times in the list and you want to remove all occurrences, you will need to put this in a loop since `list.remove()` only removes the first occurrence:

```
def deleteEntry(self, entry):
    while True:
        try:
            self.alist.remove(entry)
        except ValueError:
            return # entry was not in the list
```

Answer (score 0):

`remove()` is just a method of `list`:

```
mylist = ['foo','bar','baz']
print mylist
>>> ['foo','bar','baz']

mylist.remove('bar')
print mylist
>>> ['foo','baz']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `myList.remove("bar")` if you only need to remove one case. If you're trying to remove all of the appearances of a certain element, and/or you have several elements that you're trying to remove, you're probably better off using filter():

```
removed = ['foo', 'bar', 'zee']

myList = ['foo', 'asdf', 'bar', 'bs', 5]

myList = filter(lambda x: not x in removed, myList) #myList = ['asdf', 'bs', 5]
```